# Information needed for API https://tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/cmd/StreetSideBubbleMetaData

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I have an application where in I am loading Bing Map Tiles in Leaflet Maps.

The application has street side button. When user clicks on that button, user can choose a point on Leaflet Map and application should open Bing Map Street View, if there exists a street side for the point chosen.

I have created a hidden div, which loads Bing Map Street View when street side exists.

As I don't want Bing Maps to fallback to Bing Maps Road View, I have applied a validation by calling street side metadata api to check if (street side) metadata for the selected point exists.

But this API (http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/MetaData/Streetside/38.07451,-121.7528?key=BingMapKey), gives metadata even for the points which do not have street side associated with it.

I checked Bing Maps DEV center and found that they are applying the same validation using this api (https://tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/cmd/StreetSideBubbleMetaData).

Thus I need information on how to call this API.

The parameters needed for this API are "count", "north", "south", "east", "west", "Bing Map Key" and "g"

https://tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/cmd/StreetSideBubbleMetaData?count=50&north=28.330894132345296&south=28.32999420433954&east=-81.49337061139077&west=-81.49427053939654&key=BingMapKey&g=5061

I want to know

1. How to calculate north, south, east, west from latitude and longitude
2. How to know value of count parameter
3. How to know value of g

**Update**

Since there was an immediate down vote on this question, I wanted to add that I have been researching on this topic through various means

1. First I searched the Bing Maps Dev Center (https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk). And found out how to apply necessary validation.
2. I checked Bing Maps Rest API to get the information needed. But I cannot get any information from the Bing Map Rest API Documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/get-imagery-metadata
3. I have posted the query in Bing Maps Forum and so far do not have any satisfactory answer (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1df12c0-9e02-44ba-8123-7c3043183302/information-needed-for-api-httpstilesvirtualearthnettilescmdstreetsidebubblemetadata?forum=bingmapsservices)

Comment: Why there is a downvote on this question. I tried to search about the API on Bing Maps Rest Services but could not get the required information. I have posted the question in Bing Maps Forum (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1df12c0-9e02-44ba-8123-7c3043183302/information-needed-for-api-httpstilesvirtualearthnettilescmdstreetsidebubblemetadata?forum=bingmapsservices), but so far the question does not have satisfactory answer available. I just want to know what is wrong in asking a question which cannot be resolved through normal search.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a public API, and it's not supported for applications to be calling it directly. You should check the Bing terms of use regarding calling services, specifically section 2.a and 5.e